# Why bootstrap doesn't use an X icon for the close button?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

I always wondered why bootstrap doesn't use an X icon for the close button.

Is there any reason to not use the standard X?

Example:

[image: bootstraop modal]

Standard X (gmail.com):

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does use an "x", it uses this character to be precise: `×` (`&times;`)

[image: Bootstrap Modal dialog, X close button]

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

In your screenshot, it looks like a russian `ч`, do you happen to work with a cyrillic OS?

Comment: My bad, didn't check in other computers before asking. Probably is a font issue.

Answer (score 4):

The modal uses the HTML entity for "times" (as in multiplication) which is `&times;`. The source code from the demo on the [Bootstrap site](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) is:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
```

I'm not sure why it is being rendered as something different, it renders as an `x` on all browsers in which I view the page.

[image]

Comment: My bad, didn't check in other computers before asking. Probably is a font issue.